# Looking for an adaptor to use my computer from France in Uruguay

Tags: france, power, south-america, uruguay

I have browsed alot through Amazon to find an adaptor to use my electric stuffs bought France in Uruguay. In the description of the products they say if it can be used in Europa, USA, Australia, etc, the major countries, but I can't find nothing about Uruguay, as it is a tiny country. Therefore my question. Do you know an adaptor I can buy to run my stuffs in Uruguay.

Comment: I found a good reference at https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/uruguay/ that might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Uruguay uses 220V at 50Hz mains power supply](https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/fr/uruguay/) similarly to European countries. The plugs are mostly [type F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko), commonly known as Schuko:

[image: Type F power plug]

Or [type C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europlug), commonly known as Europlugs:

[image: type c socket]
<sub>(source: [worldstandards.eu](https://www.worldstandards.eu/WordPress/wp-content/uploads/electricity-tiles-type-C-200-px.jpg))</sub>

Coming from France, this means that in most cases **you will not need an adaptor**. However, you might find other types of sockets - type I and type L - for which an adaptor is required. This assumes that you are using appliances with type F plugs.

Comment: French plugs are actually type E, but most electronics are sold with CEE 7/7 plugs which are compatible with both type E and F (or Europlugs).